# How to check string contains substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have strings as below, I am search text order in all variables but I want to return true for `string2` and `string3` but for `string1` should be false.

```js
var string1 = "orders"
var string2 = "orders/pack"
var string3 = "orders/123"
var str = "order"
console.log(string1.includes(str)); //false 
console.log(string2.includes(str)); //true
console.log(string3.includes(str)); //true
```

Comment: From what I am seeing, all three strings contain the substring `order`.  Is there a typo, or do you want to include some more explanation?

Comment: I have created a snippet for you and the code __works__. see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: str is a substring of string1

Comment: So what is your logic for matching strings 2 and 3 but not 1? Is it just that there must be at least two additional characters?

Comment: This code returns 3 true for me.

Comment: @VincentDecaux—yes, that is the OP's problem. But they haven't provided enough information regarding how to determine true or false.

Comment: Includes check for sub string. In your code it checks whether strings contains 'order'. And we could easily say all contains substring order.

Comment: I have checked the code. it returns 3 true for me.

Comment: Can you provide the steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: from your code snipp logic should be contains the word and should contain (/) in word

Comment: The code should return true for all strings as they all contain the string "order"

Answer (score 1):

You can make check like this:

```
console.log( string1.includes(str) && (string1 != str) );
```

Comment: (string1 != str) will not work, it is matching order with orders!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var string1 = "orders"
var string2 = "orders/pack"
var string3 = "orders/123"
var str = "/"
console.log(string1.includes(str)); //false 
console.log(string2.includes(str)); //true
console.log(string3.includes(str)); //true
```

Why are you not using '/' instead of 'orders'? Any boundations which we dont know?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this it will work

```
        var string1 = "orders"
        var string2 = "orders/pack"
        var string3 = "orders/123"
        var str = "orders/"

        var result = string1.includes(str);
        console.log(result)
        var result = string2.includes(str);
        console.log(result)
        var result = string3.includes(str);
        console.log(result)
```

Comment: How is this different to the OP, other than you've appended an "s" to *str*?

Comment: include will check the given string is present or not. here all the string has order which means all the string has order so that  only it returned as true for all the result

Comment: The OP doesn't want them all to return true, the first should return false (based on some unspecified criterion).

Comment: in my case first case return false only, another case return true